# Is this safe to use postinstall in npm packages?

Tags: npm, npm-install, post-install

I want to use npm `postinstall` hook in my package to achieve my requirement. is this safe to use, I mean will it create security issues?

I am using like below:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall" : "node ./tagchange.js",
    "scripts": "gulp schematics-tasks && gulp schematics-remove && gulp adding-externals && npm run packagr",
    "bundle": "rollup -c rollup.config.js"
  },
```

Comment: Security issues like what do you mean didn't really understood your question

Comment: content security policy like that

Comment: postinstall only runs after install: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts